# Same height container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I know there are a few questions to this topic already, but I just can not get it to work.

So I have row with two cols inside and I want them to be the same height, I already tried a lot with d-flex, but it just not seems to work for me:

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-4 ce-login__col">
      <div class="ce-registration__form">
        <form id="" class="">
            <div class="ce-registration__form__top"></div>
            <div class="ce-registration__form__bottom"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-4 ce-login__col">
      <div class="ce-registration__form">
        <form id="" class="">
            <div class="ce-registration__form__top"></div>
            <div class="ce-registration__form__bottom"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `align-items-stretch`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#align-items

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-center h-100">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-4 ce-login__col text-bg-primary">
      <div class="ce-registration__form">
        <form id="" class="">
            <div class="ce-registration__form__top">A<br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div class="ce-registration__form__bottom">B</div>
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xxl-4 ce-login__col text-bg-success">
      <div class="ce-registration__form">
        <form id="" class="">
            <div class="ce-registration__form__top">C</div>
            <div class="ce-registration__form__bottom">D</div>
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but then they get the same height as their parent container and I don't want that.

Comment: Can you update your question to be more specific. Label the divs A,B,C,D or 1,2,3,4 and then explain which divs you want to be of equal height.

Currently the 2 columns in the initial row are equal height.

Comment: I think I got a solutions for my problem, so I will just delete the question, I placed the whole content in another col and row and now it works for me, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove custom heaight of colums and try `align-item:streach;`

Comment: they get the height of the parent container when I do that and I don't want them that heigh.